# regex - match some urls

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following to pick up all https or ftp from within a large string

```
/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
```

I want to extend the functionality so as NOT to pick up any URL's that have a preceding `src="` tag

Match:
`https://xxx.yyy.com`

No Match: 
`src="https://xxx.yyy.com`

I've tried the negative look behind trying to match `src="` with no success.

Comment: Why didn't you show us your attempt at using negative lookbehind?

Comment: The problem is that Javascript doesn't support lookbehindes.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript regular expressions **do not support** lookbehinds.

One common way you could match strings like this is:

```
[^"]https:\/\/[a-z.]+
```

Although you should write more detailed regex for domain, and then simply skip first character to get URL. You can see here [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN1qR5/108).

Comment: Nearly perfect, the only url which won't be matched is if the url is the first character of the input ;)

Comment: @Esteban well yes :)) But he can always prepend some character and then look for it :)

Comment: Just don't add " :)

Comment: Or add `^` alternative to `[^"]`: [`(?:[^"]|^)https:\/\/[a-z.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/sa8vG8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript. Yet you may solve this by explicitly matching the `src="` in an optional group and then filter out all matches with that group matched:

```js
var input = `Match: https://match.xxx.yyy.com
     No Match: src="https://fail.xxx.yyy.com`;
var regex = /(src=")?\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/gim;
var urls = [];

// collect only matches without `src="` prefix
input.replace(regex, function(match, src) { if (!src) {urls.push(match)} });

console.log(urls);
```